# Sizing capacity of a 1-phase breaker to feed a VFD and a 3-phase motor

Tags: motor, three-phase, vfd, circuit-breaker

I have a 3 phase 2HP motor that draws 5.8Amps at 240v

I want to feed it with a VFD with the following specs:

- VFD rated power: 4kW
- 1-phase input: 36 Amps
- 3-phase output: 18.5 Amps

The VFD is of course oversized for the motor, but I would like to use it because I already have it, my understanding is that over capacity is ok.

I would prefer to size the main panel (single phase) breaker according to expected current draw of the VFD, which should be (according to my understanding) driven by the motor.

Worst case if the breaker capacity is too low, is that it will trip.

The main breaker will be dedicated to this load (it will power the VFD and nothing else).

The reason I want to size the breaker according to expected motor draw, is that I can use smaller gauge wire, and I believe it will offer better protection for the motor and the VFD.

Questions:

1. is it a good idea ?
2. based on the above info, is it possible to size the main breaker ?

Given that the motor has a current draw of a bit less than 1/3 of the VFD output (5.8Amps vs 18.5 Amps), could the breaker Amperage also be 1/3 ?

If so, then the sizing rule of 1.5x to 2x the rated current would give me a 20Amp breaker

- min = 36*(1/3) * 1.5 = 18
- max = 36*(1/3) * 2   = 24

20 amps falls between 18 and 24